# For Loop within a for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a dataset "mapping_grouped" , in this data there is a column TrendIdentifier. Now for every entry in this dataset I need to filter the dataset RawDataSplit. Only few columns will be filtered column numbers are mentioned in the object code_match. To do this I am trying the below code, but I am doing something wrong while putting one loop into the other. I am not able to figure out the problem in this.

```
for (r in 1:nrow(mapping_grouped))
{
  current<-list()

  L1<-mapping_grouped[["TrendIdentifier"]][r]

  L1<-unlist(L1, use.names = FALSE)

  #code_match <- match(names(mastercodes), names(RawDataSplit))
  mcols<-code_match
  #mcols<-c(code_match[1]:code_match[ncol(mastercodes)])

  results_filter<-list()

  for (i in mcols) 
  { 
    filterdata<- RawDataSplit%>% filter(RawDataSplit[[i]]%in% L1)

    name_data<- paste("filterdata",i, sep = "_")
    results_filter[[name_data]] <- filterdata
  }

  filter_data<-Reduce(rbind,results_filter)

  filter_data$new_mastercode<- mapping_grouped[["Identifier"]][r]}
```

the datasets are:

```
> dput(mapping_grouped)
structure(list(Identifier = c("1000000", "1000076", "1000078", 
"1000079", "1000080", "1000081", "1000082", "1000083", "1000084", 
"1000085"), TrendIdentifier = list("1000000", "1000000", c("1001329", 
"1001340"), "1001340", "1000003", "1001126", "1001241", "1001348", 
    "1000310", "1000013")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L))

> dput(code_match)
8:10

> dput(RawDataSplit)
structure(list(identifier = c(9012286L, 9012294L, 9012296L, 9012297L, 
9012298L, 9012299L, 9012300L, 9012301L, 9012302L, 9012303L), 
    QID_1 = c(4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), QID_2 = c(4L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L), QID_3 = c(4L, 5L, 4L, 
    4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 4L), QID_4 = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L), unitlevel = c(7, 5, 6, 5, 6, 7, 7, 6, 
    7, 5), mastercode_1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), mastercode_2 = c(1000000L, 1000000L, 1000000L, 1000000L, 
    1000000L, 1000000L, 1000000L, 1000000L, 1000000L, 1000000L
    ), mastercode_3 = c(1001414L, 1000013L, 1001126L, 1001126L, 
    1000435L, 1000435L, 1000435L, 1000435L, 1000435L, 1000435L
    ), mastercode_4 = c(1001473L, 1000035L, 1001209L, 1001128L, 
    1000739L, 1000739L, 1000799L, 1000799L, 1000799L, 1000715L
    )), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000101ef0>)
```

Comment: Can you show your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Running your code I get:

```
Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds
```

Your inner loop is iterated over `i in mcols`, where `mcols` is assigned as `mcols<-code_match` and in the data you provided beforehand you have `code_match <- 77:84` which means `mcols` is `77:84`.

In the line

```r
    filterdata<- RawDataSplit%>% filter(RawDataSplit[[i]]%in% L1)
```

you are then subsetting `RawDataSplit` with the elements from `mcol` but the data frame has just 10 Columns, so the error is created by trying to get a column that doesn't exist.

Comment: Sorry, that's my fault. I shared a part of the Rawsplitdata and did not change code_match. Rawsplitdata is a very big file, so I shared a aprt of that. we can now change the code_match to c(8,9,10). Idea is we need to filter the mastercodes columns of Rawdatsplit, column numbers are in code_match.